# How can truncate a file name after a certain character

Tags: rename, mv

Due to limited knowledge of wget I have a bunch of files with names like:

```
doc1.pdf@uselessjunk    
doc1.mobi@uselessjunk
```

How can get to just the filename before the `@` symbol? There are multiple affected extensions, so I would prefer not have anything replace specific extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in *@*; do
   if ! [[ -f "${file%%@*}" ]]; then
       mv "$file" "${file%%@*}"
   else
       echo "Replacement for '$file' already exists.  Skipping."
   fi
done
```

Comment: or `mv -n` to have it not clobber in at least GNU and BSD

Comment: Good to know about `mv -n`, but I tend to err on the side of making it painfully obvious to later-me what I am doing.  Which I suppose an inline comment about `-n` would also accomplish, now that I ruminate upon it.

Comment: Doing the test in the script at least makes it obvious, but it's also a [time of check to time of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race so it's a bit worrying at least in principle. Having `mv` do the check in the actual system call could at least in theory prevent it. Not that it helps much while renaming, since `rename()` doesn't have option to not clobber, and the alternatives seem Linux-only (`renameat2()`), or semantically slightly different (`link()` + `unlink()`). Oh well.

Comment: @ilkkachu There's no `-n` flag for `mv` on OpenBSD.

Comment: You probably need `%%` in the parameter substitution as the string `hello@junk@junk` would otherwise be transformed to `hello@junk` rather than to `hello`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, oh. I guess I checked only FreeBSD and assumed that the BSDs had a more united base toolset... oh well.

Comment: @ilkkachu They've been separated so many years now that non-standard extensions in one base system won't necessarily be in the other's base system. And new stuff is not always brought over from one to the other.

Comment: Good catch, @Kusalananda; so amended.